# How to get the number of significant Eigen Value?

Tags: matlab, matrix, pca

Im working in Matlab to compute the PCA. I already compute the Eigen Value and the Eigen Vector.

I used this matlab function :

```
     [Eigen Vector, Eigen Value]=eigs(Matrix,k);
```

With this eigs function, we will get ordered Eigen Value (from big to small).

In this case, Im going to determine the **k** (which is the number of Eigen Value I want to keep).

And I need to compute k with this formula :

```
   Σ(from 1 to p) of eigen value
   ------------------------------------------------------- * 100 = our persentage
   Σ(from 1 to col of eigen value matrix) of eigen value
```

**where k=p**

And to reduce the dimension of input matrix, I just have to :

```
     (Eigen Vector*Eigen Value*Eigen Vector')
```

Someone know if there is matlab function to get the **k** number based on the persentage we want ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html).

You probably want to take the absolute value of the eigenvalues before summming:

```
P = 90; %// desired percentage
eigenValues = eigs(Matrix);
summation = cumsum(abs(eigenValues));
summation = summation/summation(end)*100; %// normalize to get percentage
k = find(summation>=P,1); %// first index for whith P is exceeded
```